# Port a flash website to iphone

Tags: mobile, flash

I would like to know if i could download the .swf file the site uses and still be able to access the site from the file? I know this is a little complicated but i'm new here. simply, download site access site servers from computer file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iphone does not support flash, and probably never will.

SWF´s are compiled flash project files(FLA´s), you can even try to decompile it, but FLA´s are always better.

A SWF that runs locally needs to be standalone, not making use of external resources. If they´re used, should be using relative paths, even if you download the resources, you need access to source code, fonts and other stuff to change it according to your needs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In other words: no. What you're asking is not feasible.